# SH, can't make equality work

Tags: shell, ssh, command-line, command

I'm trying to get a simple if statement to work.

```
if [ $sip1 = 0 ] ; then do stuff ; fi
```

My below `sh` line shows the struggle i'm dealing with.

I can't get it to acknowledge the 0 i've stored as an integer, and if i compare it to a string, it says it's not a match.

```
# if [ `expr $sip1` ] ; then echo hi
> fi
hi
# if [ `expr $sip1 = 1` ] ; then echo hi; fi
hi
# if [ `expr $sip1 = 2` ] ; then echo hi; fi
hi
# expr $sip1
0
# if [ `expr $sip1 + 0 = 2` ] ; echo hi
>
# if [ `expr $sip1 + 0 = 2` ] ; then echo hi
> fi
expr: non-numeric argument
# echo $sip1
0
# if [ $sip1 = "0" ] ; then echo hi ; fi
# if [ $sip1 = '0' ] ; then echo hi ; fi
# echo ">$sip1<"
<0
```

Comment: What is output of `echo ">$sip1<"` please. Add it to your question. Also, your first part asks about `$sip` and the second section asks about `$sip1`; you realise these are different variables?

Comment: Corrected, and they're a single variable, just a typo.

Comment: You need `fi` at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `echo` that you posted:

```bash
# echo ">$sip1<"
<0
```

Indicates that the value of variable `sip1` is not `0`, as you probably expected, but rather `0` followed by a carriage return character (`$'0\r'` in Bash syntax):

```bash
$ zero_cr=$'0\r'
$ if [ "$zero_cr" = "0" ] ; then echo hi ; fi
$ zero='0'
$ if [ "$zero" = "0" ] ; then echo hi ; fi
hi
## Or, using the proper numeric equality operator:
$ if [ "$zero" -eq "0" ] ; then echo hi ; fi
hi
```

Depending on exactly how you populated your variable, consider stripping the carriage return character from it:

- If your code is something like `sip1=$(command...)`, then `sip1=$(command... | tr -d '\r')` should get rid of any stray carriage return characters, and let your tests be successful.
- Or, assuming Bash, deleting a trailing carriage return character appears to work using syntax `${foo%$'\r'}`, so that `sip1=${sip1%$'\r'}` should cleanse your variable of its trailing carriage return.

Comment: I used your suggestion to strip the carriage return, working fine now. Thanks a million.

Comment: For numeric comparison you should use `-eq` rather than `=`

Comment: @roaima: I agree, but also I believe that the only string representation for zero is `0`, so would there be a benefit in using `-eq`? (Perhaps that would have stripped the carriage return by itself?)

Comment: Zero can be represented also as `00`. A trailing CR breaks numeric comparison too - `seq=$'0\r'; [ $seq -eq 0 ]` results in `: integer expression expected`